# Mongoose - How to save results to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb query and I want to save the results to an array. I also define an empty array outside of query.

```
       var dietaryResults = [];

       for (var key in dietary){
            Restaurant.find(
                { $text : { $search : dietary[key] } },
                { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
            ).sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } }).exec(function(err, results) {
                for (var i in results){
                    dietaryResults.push(results[i]);
                }
                console.log(dietaryResults);
            });
        }
```

If I do `console.log(dietaryResults)` inside the query like above, I can see the results being pushed into the array. But if I put `console.log(dietaryResults)` outside of the array (which what I want), it prints an empty string. Can anyone explain this behavior and suggest a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain what you meant by "But if I put console.log(dietaryResults) outside of the array"? Did you mean outside of the callback or outside of the nested for-loop?

Comment: I mean outside of this `Restaurant.find(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use `bluebird` (which is a kind of `Promise`) it works.

```
 var Promise = require('bluebird');
 var mongoose = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));

 var promises = Restaurant.find({ $text : { $search : query } }, function(err, results) {
     results.forEach(function(element) {
         finalResults.push(element);
     });
 });

 Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
     console.log(finalResults);
 }).error(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

Restaurant.find is asynchronous.

Function insinde .exec part is being executed after loop ends.

Try

```
 for (var key in dietary){
        Restaurant.find(
            { $text : { $search : dietary[key] } },
            { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
        ).sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } }).exec(function(err, results) {
            for (var i in results){
                dietaryResults.push(results[i]);
            }
            console.log('added');
        });
    }
 console.log('loop end');
```

You will be able to see, that 'loop end' log will be printed before 'added' log.
If you need all results in array, you should fill this array in callback. There is no way to get data synchronously.

For more information about callbacks and async functions check out this article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm

I'd suggest to search for all required data at once and avoid searching inside loop to have single callback and do everything you need with results inside that callback.

Smth like this may work. If not you should search for some way to get all data in one request

```
 Restaurant.find(
    { $text : { $search : { $in: Object.values(dietary)} } },
    { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
 ).sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } }).exec(function(err, results) {
    for (var i in results){
        dietaryResults.push(results[i]);
    }
        //do stuff here;
    });
```

Comment: How is this code any different than the OPs? Explain a solution!  This is not about NodeJS, it is about Mongoosejs.

Comment: @RandyCasburn My code will help to undestand when parts of code are executed. Author will be able to see that 'loop end' will be printed before 'added'. So, I'm explaining behaviour, as it is asked in post.

Comment: I realize that, but when they don't understand async ops in the first place they will not know that without you explaining what you are doing for them. I'm try to avoid a downvote on your answer. Please explain your purpose in your answer.

Comment: @ŞükranEken Tell me whats wrong)  I don't think that I should explain all async concept here. I've posted link to it.

Comment: @MichaelKapustey - great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need callback or promise.You can use outside of this **Restaurant.find( **
this:`setTimeOut(function s(){console.log(dietaryResults)},1000)`

Because you need to learn async functions.

Comment: I just wanna print out the results for testing purpose. In real, I would want to pass the results to somewhere else, does it still work that way?

Answer (score 0):

As of [javascript asynchronicity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Asynchronous) fashion, You can't be sure that the `.exec` callback will run (and end) before the for loop end. (you can have a better understanding on this topic by reading about the [event-loop](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-understanding-node-js-event-loop/))

This way, `dietaryResults` can be empty (depend on the query speed) in any other place.

[You can read more about using promises with mongoose and node in order to be sure `dietaryResults` will be full with the results](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises),
and also have better understanding on this topic by reading about [Node event loop](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-understanding-node-js-event-loop/).

For now, I'm not fully sure this will work - but that's is your direction:

```
var query = {...} // (enter your query here) 
var dietaryResults = [];

Object.entries(diatery).map(async key => {
  const results = await Restaurant.find(query).sort();
  results.map(result => dietaryResults.push(result));
});

console.log(dietaryResults);
```